# Stop overflow-x on mobile iOS and android

Tags: android, ios, css

I have a side menu that hides behind the main content until a toggle is pressed, at which point the content slides right (via a `margin-left`) to reveal the menu.

Everything works great, but on mobile the user is able to reposition the menu by sliding/swiping from right to left, so that the entire pane scrolls.  This is not desirable because it is confusing to the user.  I've demonstrated it in this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/lC3TUtqBrCyXzaJfOGzY?p=preview

The `overflow-x: hidden` applied to `html` and `body` appear to work in chrome dev's spoofed version of mobile, but when I check it with an actual android device or in the iOS emulator, the entire pane still scrolls left-right.

Is there a simple CSS workaround to this?  If it's relevant, I only need modern browser support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, mobile browsers don't seem to respect `overflow-x` as they should.  So the solution in my case was to add `overflow: hidden` to the `html` and `body` elements to fully constrain scrolling, then to override the y-scroll with `overflow-y: scroll` on the elements that need it.

And it works like a charm!